# Docker Permission Denied Only on RHEL 6.6

Tags: nginx, docker, redhat, rhel

So I have a challenge and need a nudge in the right direction.  We stood up docker in a new environment with RedHat 6.6 and while it seems to be functioning normally things that are read from inside the container seem to have permission issues.

As an example:

Using the nginx:1 image (pulled from the docker hub) it works on my Macbook and on CentOS 6.6, and Rhel 6.5 servers, but not in RHEL 6.6.  When it works you get the default welcome to Nginx page.  When it doesn't work you get an HTTP 403 error.  In the nginx logs the error message is /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html permission denied.

I've tried the httpd web server image (from the docker hub) as well and have had the same experience in RHEL 6.6 while it works everywhere else.

Any suggestions would be great.

Notes:
The kernels on RHEL 6.5 and RHEL 6.6 are the same and we are using docker 1.5 with same version of go 1.7.

Comment: Perhaps better asked on http://serverfault.com

Comment: I wonder if selinux is enabled on the host, and if it is, if putting it in permissive mode allows things to work as expected (`setenforce 0`).  If this is the case, you will either need to update your selinux configuration or persistently disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The mnt directory for docker /opt/docker/devicemapper/mnt had the incorrect file permission across the board.  A little chmod -R 755 to /opt/docker/devicemapper/mnt and viola it's working.

Comment: But Docker Defaults to the wrong permission every time a new container is run.

Comment: did you figure how resolve this issue rather then chmod 755 everytime a new container is created?